# How to get the path of a selected folder without JFileChooser?

Tags: java, file, path

Is it possible to get the path of **selected folder** in Windows with out using `JFileChooser`, for e.g. :-

I'm click **My Documents** folder and get the  **path of My Documents  folder**.

Comment: You click MyDoucments folder: where? In which application?

Comment: yes no issue with, for better help sooner post an  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: i want to create an application that takes the path of the folder i selected in windows. how do i know what folder is selected ?

Comment: windows is not an application. It's an operating system. Do you mean "the Windows Explorer"? If so, you could have 20 Explorer windows opened, each with a different selected folder. So obviously, this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JB Nizet yes like windows explorer. But how my application detect which folder is selected?

Comment: You can't. It's impossible.

Answer (score -1):

String FolderLocation = new File(folderLocation).getAbsolutePath();

This will return, in the string FolderLocation, the full path to the folder/file that is specified in the string folderLocation. for example:
"C:\Users*user*\Documents"